# Casting character to integer using static cast not working?

Tags: c++, xcode, casting, static-cast

I have this program and the function I am having an issue with is stringLength function. I can't change the function declaration as it was given to us by our prof. The issue I am having a problem with is static casting the integer (in this case i) to a character to insert it into the character array. I looked it up online and apparently doing this

```
A[0]= char(i+48);
```

This works but I don't want to use this because I got this off the internet.
What I want to use is

```
A[0] = static_cast<char>(i);
```

If there is another way to cast it or a simple way that would be much appreciated. I even tried doing

```
 A[0] = i; 
 A[0] = char(i); //or this
```

Here is my whole program. The last function is the function I am having a problem with

**EDIT:** The output I want to achieve lets say the string I use is "Bonjour"
the output I want it to say is "7Bonjour". The problem with my static cast is nothing shows up before Bonjour. The length of the string is supposed to appear before the string

**EDIT 2:** I simplified the code to only include the important functions and stuff regarding my question

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream in ("input.txt");
ofstream out ("output.txt");

void stringCopy(char *A, char *B);
bool stringCompare(char *A, char *B);
void stringConcatenation (char *A, char *B);
int stringPosition(char *A, char B);
int stringLength(char *A);
int main (){
char str1[15], str2[15];
char pos;
int number;

if(!in){
    cout << "File not opening" << endl;
}
else{
cout << "File opened" << endl;
}

in >> str1;
stringLength(str1);
out << " Contents of the array after string Length: " << str1 << endl;



in.close();
out.close();
}
void stringConcatenation (char *A, char *B){
int i;
int j;
for (i = 0; A[i]!='\0';i++){ // find the last position of the first string  
}
for (j = 0; B[j]!='\0';j++){
    A[i++] = B[j]; // add the first letter of the second string to the next spot of the first string
    A[i]='\0';
}
}
int stringLength(char *A){
char arr[15];
int i = 0;
while (A[i]!='\0'){
    arr[i]=A[i];
    i++; // increment i one more to store NULL position in temp array
}
arr[i]='\0'; //set last position of the temp array to NULL
A[0]= static_cast<char>(i); //static cast i to char and add to first position
A[1]= '\0'; // sets the last position of the first array for the string concatenation to work and detect end of array
stringConcatenation(A, arr);
return i;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what problem you have with the cast. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: The Integer doesn't appear before the word. If I use the string "Bonjour" when I want it to say "7Bonjour" but instead the output only is "Bonjour"

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with `static_cast`, you must do this:

```
A[0] = static_cast<char>(i + 48);
```

What static cast actually does is that it casts int to char with the corresponding ASCII value. Because ASCII value of '0' is 48, for `i <= 9`, it will give correct output.

But this approach won't work if `i >= 10`.

Instead, you must do this:

```
strcpy(A, to_string(i).c_str());
```